# Retrofit and RxJava, Android multi-threaded REST requests

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, retrofit2

So I'm quite new to Reactive programming, after following this [tuto](http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/) I'm able to send multi-threaded REST requests like so:

Retrofit2 interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("path")
Observable<String> putMethod(
    @Field("field") String field,
    ...
);
```

Retrofit2 builder:

```
private NetRequestService() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(END_POINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
}
```

Request:

```
public void putMethod(Context context, List<Object> objectList){

    for(Object o: objectList) {
        service.putMethod(
                "field",
                ...
        )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onNext(String response) {
                        Log.e("Response", response);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, the problem is that the onCompleted() method is called for each call (as expected) but I'd like to know when all calls to service.putMethod(...) are completed. How can I do that? I'd like to have some sort of callback when all calls are done to perform another action.

Thanks

Comment: The answer below is right, but i want to add that you should think twice before using Schedulers.newThread. Use special scheduler 'io'. The reason is that newThread creates new thred for each method call, when io scheduler uses thread pool for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
    Observable
            .fromIterable(list)
            .flatMap(object -> service.putMethod(/* ... */))
            .ignoreElements()
            .subscribe(/* ... */)
```

This will discard the results though, you will only get the onComplete. If you're interested in the results, you could put them in a List or some other object:

```
    Observable
            .fromIterable(list)
            .flatMap(object -> service.putMethod(/* ... */))
            .toList()
            .subscribe(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Right, and add. subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())